# Does GDB in RISC-V support Program Context aware breakpoint?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, fedora, qemu, riscv

I would like to learn if existing GDB for RISC-V supports Program Context aware breakpoints?

By program context aware breakpoints : I mean, when there is JAL or JALR instruction PC changes when there is a function call. in other cases in Function call ==> PC = PC + (Current Program Counter + 4)
in Function Return : PC = PC - (Return address (ra register value) ).

I have installed fedora(risc-V) on my ubuntu(virtual machine). Since it is virtual machine I can't print PC register value, that is why I couldn't check if it supports Program Context aware breakpoint or not?

My second question is : How can I print PC register value on my qemu risc-v virtual machine?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check_prime(int a)
{
int c; 
    for (c=2;c<a;c++)
    {
        if (a%c == 0 ) return 0; 
        if (c == a-1 ) return 1; 
    }
}

void oddn(int a)
{
    printf("oddn --> %d is an odd number \n",a);
    if (check_prime(a)) printf("oddn --> %d is a prime number\n",a);
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    a=7;
    if (check_prime(a)) printf("%d is a prime number \n",a);
        if (a%2==1) oddn(a);    

}
```

This is the program I am trying to breakpoint using GDB.

[image: The result of GDB breakpoint]

As you see on the picture it breaks twice(which should break **once only**).
It also gives error :

```
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Invalid data type for function to be called
```

Comment: Even with your description it's not clear what you mean by 'Program Context aware breakpoints'.  GDB ultimately places breakpoints at addresses.  GDB can figure out a suitable address based on a file and line number, or a function name, but internally these all get mapped to an address, which is where the breakpoint is placed.  You can also place a breakpoint at a specific address if required.  In what way are 'Program Context aware breakpoints' different?

Comment: If a program is running in order(in one function without jumps) then the program counter is always PC=PC+4, but whenever there is JAL or JALR program counter value changes more than 4 (PC=PC+100 for example). Whenever it goes to evenn function, PC = PC + evenn_address, and whenever it returns PC=PC - evenn_address. By calculating these adresses I want to set breakpoint when it reaches functionC from functionD exactly. for ex: 1. main --> functionD (no need for breakpoint) 2. main --> functionC --> functionD(Here I want to set breakpoint)(Rhis one is program context)

Comment: I can reproduce the error you are seeing.  There are two things that might cause this issue I think, (1) older gdb version.  These functions were added in GDB 7.9, so consider updating if you are using something older (`show version` at a gdb prompt), or (2) these functions are actually implemented as Python extensions that ship with GDB.  So you'll need a GDB built with Python support and installed correctly.  At a gdb prompt type `python print ("hello")` to check you have Python support.

Comment: The version is : GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1 and it doesn't support python. As I know starting from GDB 7.3 it should support python but it doesn't.

Comment: It supports python script on GDB too. Now I have written convenience function in python and would like to use it. Just copying it to ~/gdb/python/lib/gdb/function would be enough to use it or are there any procedures that I should do in order to use it?

Comment: If you now have a version of GDB that supports Python, does that mean the `$_caller_is` problem you had is now resolved?

Comment: Yeah, $_caller_is is working fine now. But I have implemented another function context_checker.py and placed it in ~/gdb/python/lib/gdb/function/, when I call $_context_checker it is not responding. Are there any other procedures that I should do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is documented here:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html#index-_0024_005fstreq_002c-convenience-function

You should look at `$_caller_is`, `$_caller_matches`, `$_any_caller_is`, and `$_any_caller_matches`.

As an example, to check if the immediate caller is a particular function we could do this:

```
break functionD if ($_caller_is ("functionC"))
```

Then `main -> functionD` will not trigger the breakpoint, while `main -> functionC -> functionD` will trigger the breakpoint.

The convenience functions I listed all take a frame offset that can be used to specify which frame GDB will check (for `$_caller_is` and `$_caller_matches`) or to limit the range of frames checked (for `$_any_caller_is` and `$_any_caller_matches`).